# ListBox multiple selection mode not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listitem

I have an asp:ListBox that I'm dynamically generating items for. The Selection mode is set to "multiple" but I can only select one item

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstLanguages" SelectionMode="multiple" Width="200">
</asp:ListBox>
```

---

```
var languages = GetSiteLanguages();
foreach (var lang in languages)
{
    lstLanguages.Items.Add(new ListItem(lang.Name));
}
lstLanguages.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
```

I tried setting the selection mode both in the aspx file and in the code behind but it's not working.

Comment: We could not reproduce the problem with the above code. Could you create [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This would be a stupid question and might be rude but have you tried using shift or control keys or even dragging the mouse to highlight the items? Because both of your code should work.

Comment: Ha, that might actually be it. PEBKAC

Answer (score 1):

You are adding Items in a wrong way in the ListBox. 
The correct way to add items is:

```
    var languages = GetSiteLanguages();
    foreach (var lang in languages)
    {
        lstLanguages.Items.Add(lang); //lang should be a string value.
    }
```

Note: I am supposing that the "languages" is a List of Strings.

Comment: Add method has two overloads. Either way is correct.